# Ambiguous reference between 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color' & 'System.Drawing'

Tags: c#, colors, bitmap, system.drawing, ambiguous

I think this is a simple question to answer, but I still can't figure out a way to get past it.

Basically, what I wanted, was to use a `Bitmap` object in my Xna game. So I went ahead and added `System.Drawing` as an assembly reference. This worked out perfectly, except that I now get a different error; "'Color' is an ambiguous reference between 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color' and 'System.Drawing'. How do I get past this?

Comment: What about using fully qualified names? `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color` instead of just `Color`

Comment: Now I really don't know what you mean, and I can only assume you meant the tag, and I can also assume that you are just here to spam and troll. What about answering the question instead of being rude?

Comment: You misunderstand. [Check out this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Well that was awkward. Sorry for getting defensive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assembly reference alone doesn't lead to the error. It's the `using` that you've probably inserted, because it imports the whole namespace. You could try

```
using Bitmap = System.Drawing.Bitmap
```

instead to import the bitmap only.